# Why am I unable to load an audio file with torchaudio whenever I use a GPU on kaggle?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, kaggle, torchaudio

I am trying to fine-tune wav2vec2 model for audio recognition task using a small custom dataset on kaggle that is made up of m4a audio files.

When I ran my code earlier today without an accelerator (GPU) and loaded my audio files using torchaudio.load(). Everything worked fine. I got a output without error.

However, whenever I run a session with a accelerator (GPU P100, GPU T4 x2) etc I am getting the following error:

`RuntimeError: Failed to load audio from /kaggle/input/personal-audio/Date3.m4a`

I have isolated the part of code into another notebook and executed it to confirm that the only trigger for this error seems to be whether I have an accelerator or I do not. Restarting the kernel does not work, nor does switching to completely new notebook and copying my code. I have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is different when you load the data into a single GPU or GPUs. It means that you should indicate that where do you process the data.

Normally, Pytorch use following code:

`Object.to(device)`

But, your case might be different with the one if you use another module, which is not PyTorch. So, please indicate that what moduel you are using to load the data. And what do you want to process the data following the step. Kaggle is not main thing to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm using the torchaudio.load() function to load a audio file as a tensor (nothing else). By default it would be loaded into the cpu, GPU or not mustn't be a problem and the Torch.to() function is used to move a pytorch related object from cpu to GPU manually so it's optional. That is why I am saying the issue seems to be how the kaggle environment interacts with torchaudio library.